# angular-google-maps windows options usage and customizing it

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, angular-google-maps

Hi Pardon me if this is repeat question or obvious one as i am new to programming

I am trying to implement an angular google map using [this api](https://angular-ui.github.io/angular-google-maps/#!/api). it has a property called options `boxClass,boxStyle,content,disableAutoPan,maxWidth,pixelOffset,alignBottom,position,zIndex,closeBoxMargin,closeBoxURL,infoBoxClearance,isHidden,visible,enableEventPropagation` as different values(seen from the JS file.)

Now i want to know what each one of those will do as it is not specified in their documentation. and mostly i wanna know how i can make the info window to appear on rightside of marker like shown [here](http://html.realsite.byaviators.com/headers-google-map.html) I designied the html for the infobox and when i give `boxClass` as the option the infobox is rendered properly but is displaying below the marker. i want it to be to the side of marker.

EDIT: let me clarify on certain points. I mainly wanted to know

1.how to remove the default close button and replace with mine. (which function to call for it to work )

2.how to use pixelOffset or another property to help me display the infobox to the side of marker as in example above without using margin or padding. [gmaps api v3](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#InfoWindowOptions) specify the pixelOffset to be of type size. i tried various ways to offset the infobox so that it will shift but it seems i am using it wrong as the box either wont change its position or will be displayed at the top of map irrespective of the marker.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of them are CSS properties that changes appearance and not really maps term. You can google them or learn from [**here**](http://www.w3schools.com/css/default.asp).